# Havin a error with working a collection after deserialize json

Tags: java, json, parsing, collections

I have a problem working on a collection when deserializing json into a Treemap collection. It, has this error:

class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class data.Worker (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; data.Worker is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I have tried to change timezone, but i think, that main problem was a deleting a worker string after saving my Treemap into json.

before parse

`{1=Worker{id=56, name='zeleboba', coordinates=Coordinates{x=14, y=88.0}, creationDate=2024-03-23T15:53:35.294467, salary=2.1421412E7, endDate=null, position=CLEANER, status=FIRED, organization='foobar'}}`

it after

`{1={id=56, name=zeleboba, coordinates={x=14, y=88.0}, creationDate=2024-03-23T15:53:35.294467, salary=2.1421412E7, endDate=null, position=CLEANER, status=FIRED, organization=foobar}}`

Comment: What serialization framework are you using, Jackson, etc?

Comment: Hi, @Tikhon and welcome to StackOverflow! :) When asking a question, it is important to attach the code that is giving you an error, so that the community can help you to figure out what's wrong. Please attach a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code